# Poisson Problem, Fictitious Domain Method, Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier, finite-element-method

Consider the problem
\begin{align} 
- \Delta u &= f  & in \text{ } \omega \\
u &= g & on \text{ } \gamma 
\end{align}
$\omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$ $(d\ge0)$ and $\gamma$ its boundary $\delta \omega$.
We assume that $u \in H^1(\omega)$, $f \in L^2(\omega)$ and $g \in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\gamma)$.

Let us consider a 'box' $\Omega$ which is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\omega \subseteq \Omega$.
Now I want to derive the weak form by the Lagrange Multiplier Method.
The corresponding minimization problem:
$$
u = \arg\min_{v \in H^1(\Omega),\\ v = g \text{ on } \gamma } \frac12 \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_\Omega fv\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
We define a Lagrangian functional $\mathscr{L}: H^1(\Omega) \times H^{-\frac12}(\gamma)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
\mathscr{L} (v, \mu) = \frac12 \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_\Omega \tilde{f}v\,\mathrm{d}x- <\mu, v - g>$$
where $\tilde{f} \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\tilde{f}|_{\omega}=f$, $<.,.>$ denotes the duality pairing between $H^{-\frac12}(\gamma)$ and $H^{\frac12}(\gamma)$.
How can I derive this two equations:
\begin{aligned}
\int_\Omega \nabla \tilde{u} \cdot \nabla v \,\mathrm{d}x&=
\int_\Omega \tilde{f}v\,\mathrm{d}x +
<\lambda, v> 
\quad &\forall v \in H^1(\Omega),\\
<\mu, \tilde{u}-g> &= 0 \quad &\forall \mu \in H^{-\frac12}(\gamma),\\
\end{aligned}
$\tilde{u} \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\lambda \in H^{-\frac12}(\gamma)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first (or the second) equation is equivalent to setting the Fréchet derivative of the Lagrangian with respect $v$ (or with respect to $\mu$) to zero.

An example how to obtain the first equation:
$$0 = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}(u + \epsilon v, \lambda)}{\partial \epsilon}\Bigg|_{\epsilon = 0} = \int_\Omega \nabla (u+\epsilon v) \cdot \nabla v \,\mathrm{d}x - \int_\Omega f v \,\mathrm{d}x + \langle \lambda, v \rangle \Bigg|_{\epsilon = 0}$$
This holds for any direction $v \in H^1(\Omega)$.
Remark: It seems to me that your sign for $\langle \lambda, v \rangle$  is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. Yes you are right, the sign in front of the $<\mu, v - g>$ in $\mathscr{L} (v, \mu)$ was wrong. I changed it now from $+$ to $-$.

Comment: Just curious: What is your end goal? Are you planning to use this method in practice?

Comment: I use the Nitsche method in practice. I just want to compare Nitsche to Lagrangian and to Penalty in my master thesis. The goal is to find a fictitious domain method which can be calculated very fast. It will be used in cancer therapy.

Comment: Maybe you are already aware of the connection between Nitsche's method and Lagrange multiplier method, but nevertheless see the [paper by R. Stenberg](http://math.aalto.fi/~rstenber/Publications/Nitsche95.pdf) on the subject. Especially page 146 where he demonstrates that the Nitsche's method is a special case of the stabilized Lagrange multiplier method.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will have a look at it.